# Why does System.Drawing.Fontconverter.ConvertFromInvariantString("NOTAFONT") return SansSerif?

Tags: c#, serialization, fonts

Why does

```
var fontConverter = new FontConverter();            
var retFont = fontConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString("NOTAFONT");

return {Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif" Size=8.25}
```

and does not throw an exception?

With this code I intend to test a string if it contains a valid font serialization. Are there other ways to check this?

I checked the code of the FontConverter class and it creates the returnfont like this:

```
 var retFont = new Font("notafont", 1.2f, FontStyle.Bold);
```

The returned font is {Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif" Size=1.2}

Comment: How are you testing, you can get an enumeration of the installed fonts and check that your string matches an available font.

Comment: @Mark: See my update (IsFontStringValid)

Comment: please don't copy the accepted answer to the question. There's no point in doing so and it might confuse the voters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking under the [MSDN Documentation on the Font Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font(v=vs.110).aspx) the remarks section has an interesting statement.

i.e.:

> For more information about how to construct fonts, see How to: Construct Font Families and Fonts. Windows Forms applications support TrueType fonts and have limited support for OpenType fonts. **If you attempt to use a font that is not supported, or the font is not installed on the machine that is running the application, the Microsoft Sans Serif font will be substituted**.

I think you are seeing this behavior.

Not sure if this will meet your need but in this case I am using the [`InstalledFontCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify that the font is available.

```
bool CheckFontAvailability(string value)
{
    FontCollection fc = new InstalledFontCollection();
    return fc.Families.Any(ff => ff.Name.Contains(value));
}
```

---

or as modified by schoetbi

```
 bool CheckFontAvailability(string fontAsString)
{
    FontCollection fc = new InstalledFontCollection(); 
    return fc.Families.Any(ff => fontAsString.StartsWith(ff.Name));
}
```

Comment: Thanks that you found it. It is not mentioned for the FontConverter class.

Comment: Very good: I just modified your solution to match also full fontString with style See my update.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you always get the "Microsoft Sans Serif" font if your given font can not be found and is not available. I tried it out with both the [FontConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class and the [Font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

I tried it with

```
var font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
```

and got the Arial font as specified.

<del>I could not find any remark on this topic on MSDN that "Microsoft Sans Serif" is always returned if the given font can not be found.</del>

Comment: You are right. My current implementation is to convert the font back to a string and check if the font family of this string starts with the same value as my original input string. Not a beautiful solution.